# UIWebView leaking when displaying large PDFs on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, memory-leaks, uiwebview

Here's some strange behavior I hope someone can confirm is a known bug, or suggest a workaround.

My iPad app needs to display some large PDFs (~7mb and graphics-heavy.) The path of least resistance is of course a UIWebView, but my app crashes after display of a few. I isolated the behavior in a new project, and ran Instruments on it.

Here are the results. They seem to indicate that bad leaks are happening in UIWebView.

The essential code, in a minimal view controller:

```
-(IBAction)doPresent:(UIView *)sender
{
  NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sender tag]]
                                       withExtension:@"pdf"];
  UIWebView *wv = [[[UIWebView alloc] init] autorelease];
  UIViewController *vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
  [vc setView:wv];
  UINavigationController *holder = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc] autorelease];

  [self presentModalViewController:holder animated:YES];
  [wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

  UIBarButtonItem *close = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                          target:self
                                                                          action:@selector(doDismiss:)] autorelease];
  [[vc navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:close];
}

-(IBAction)doDismiss:(id)sender
{
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Not pictured: the main nib containing this VC, its view, and five buttons connected to `doPresent:`, each tagged with 1...5; and 1.pdf through 5.pdf in the app bundle. Run it and it works much as you'd expect, except that it crashes after a half-dozen or so views of the PDFs.

Running it under Instruments (allocations) yielded this interesting plot:
[image: plot of memory usage]

The pattern I notice is that, if I display a PDF and dismiss it **without scrolling around the document**, it's released as expected with minimal leakage. But if I touch it and scroll, even a little, the memory is not released. Viewing subsequent PDFs does not appear to reuse any of the wasted memory but each allocates more of its own. Running in the simulator and triggering memory warnings doesn't get this memory back either.

When usage hit ~ 25mb, the program got `kill -9`'d. This seems low to me, suggesting some other resource is being leaked besides app memory.

This is on a iPad 1, running 4.3, freshly rebooted.

Ideas? Workarounds? Foolish omissions on my part?

Comment: It looks like you are creating a new UIWebView each time.  Is it different if you recycle the same view?  A solution to a vaguely related problem we had was to load an empty page like `about:blank` before dismissing any web view.

Comment: I have not tried the about:blank trick. that might be worth a look.

Comment: recycling the web view somewhat mitigates but does not eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Apple finally got back to me on the bug report, and they recognize the bug and claim it's fixed in the latest ios 5.x builds. We'll see.

Comment: I have the same problem and tried multiple different ways to present the PDF including the Leaves class. The result was always the same and eventually the app would crash after loading 8-9 PDF. Can't wait to try it on IOS 5 after I saw your post.

Comment: Link to issue and Apple's answer?

Comment: I am still facing this memory leak in iPhone 5S, with iOS 7.1.1. I don't think this has been fixed from Apple.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on iOS 9.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I think user:"drawnonward" is on to something. Looking at your code, with each button press you not only alloc and init a new webview, but also a new UIViewController, and a new UINavigationController. Unless it is absolutely necessary to create a new instance of each of these objects each time a button is pressed, you should re-code so that you have only one instance of each object, and then with each button press load new content into the webview.

I think there is a really good chance that this fixes your problem.

Comment: ...but I don't *leak* them, which is the thing. Using UINavigationControllers as throwaways is an OK, apple-endorsed pattern I've used to great effect elsewhere, and it's safe as long as you clean up after yourself.

Comment: I don't recall saying that you were leaking them. The point I would like to make is that by recycling the NavController, ViewController, and WebView, you can minimize your allocations, which (in theory) would also fix your issue. When setting an object to autorelease, it doesn't release the second you are done with the object, instead it adds the object to the pool. The object stays in memory until the pool is drained. In any case, hopefully Apple really has fixed this for iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I always go back from the PDF in the webview. If you scoll to top using something like this:

```
for (UIView *subview in webView.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        [subview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

It seems to fix the issue

Comment: I was having a similar problem with UIWebView crashing on the iPad when I closed the enclosing UIViewController and the content was still actively scrolling at the time due to the "inertia" effect. This fixed it for me.